# Cookies appear in chrome lock-icon menu but not in DevTools > Application Tab > Cookies section?

Tags: google-chrome, web, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

I was checking the Application tab in the Chrome DevTools to debug an analytics issue and I noticed that the cookies section was empty, although the cookies menu under the lock icon in the chrome search bar seemed to show the cookie that I was interested in.

I did a bunch of refreshing, clearing site data, and restarting Chrome with no change in behaviour.

**Is this a bug in Chrome? Why is there a discrepancy between the two menus? Does it have to do with `httpOnly` or `secure` cookies?**

Not a very important question, mostly just curious!

Comment: Compare the cookies and then inspect the different ones. Maybe there's a clue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an authoritative answer on this, but I think the explanation is in the language on top of this dialog: It says "The following cookies were set when you viewed this page". So it just shows whatever was set originally – or even "at some point" when you viewed the page. The message is not clear on this detail.

I can definitely confirm from my own tests that it will keep listing cookies that have since been deleted. Dev tools however always show the current state of cookie storage.

Whether it's a bug or not I suppose one could discuss at length, seeing as the behavior is not in conflict with the description. But it's certainly not expected behavior, and its usefulness for non-technical users is I think at least questionable.

This also lists "folder" type entries for indexed DBs, local storage and session storage which are not useful at all because you can't drill down. All of this and the missing punctuation on the message on top makes me think this is orphaned or forgotten code.

I also have no idea where that info is stored or how one might be able to purge it.

ETA: After some more experience with this discrepancy, I have since come to the conclusion that the list shown via the lock icon will show any kind of write access to the cookies. Since there is no dedicated "delete" operation for cookies, but you delete them by *setting* them with an expiration time in the past, deletions would still count as write access. So it looks pretty much like the dev tools seem to be only showing cookies that are still *effectively* there, i.e., would be sent to the server in a request, while the list in the lock icon is just a log of write accesses to cookie storage. This is still not definitive, but completely fits all my observations so far.